# Pandas group by event id and relative time bins of each event?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I wanted to know the fastest way to group my data into events and each event into 4 bins based on the duration of that event and count the instances in each bin.
My data looks like this:

```
time    eventID    value
0:30     1          a
0:30     1          b
0:30     1          c
4:00     1          d
1:00     2          a
2:00     2          b
3:00     2          c
4:00     2          d
5:00     2          e
6:00     2          f
7:00     2          g
8:00     2          h
```

And the output should look like this:

```
event    bin    count
1        1       3
1        2       0
1        3       0
1        4       1
2        1       2
2        2       2
2        3       2
2        4       2
```

And also the number of bins and times could be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can compute a custom bin with [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) then use it to [`GroupBy.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

```
N = 4
bins = (df.groupby('eventID')['time']
                                  # assuming input is HH:MM, adding :00 (SS)
          .apply(lambda d: pd.cut(pd.to_timedelta(d+':00')
                                  bins=N, labels=range(1, N+1)))
       )

out = (df.groupby(['eventID', bins.rename('bin')])['value']
         .count().reset_index()
       )
```

output:

```
   eventID bin  value
0        1   1      3
1        1   2      0
2        1   3      0
3        1   4      1
4        2   1      2
5        2   2      2
6        2   3      2
7        2   4      2
```

Comment: Is there a faster way that doesn't involve applying a lambda function on each record?

Comment: No, you need to apply `cut` on each group independently